# Creation of fragments in proper way

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am new to android development.Recently i started developing apps using fragments.I did search some tutorials and tried working with fragments.In my app i am using a navigation drawer.Now suppose if user is on frag A and if the user again selects frag A the frag A is again created leaving the previous frag A in back stack.Now how should i construct my frag to make it very optimize.

Code which i have written

```
public class MasterFragment extends Fragment {
    protected static Context context;
    private FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    protected View view;
    private AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    protected File file;
    String fileSeperator = "/";
    private InputMethodManager inputMethodManager;
    private static String boundary = "*****";
    private static String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    private static String twoHyphens = "--";
    private File f;
    private String response;


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        context = getActivity();
    }


    protected void startFragment(Fragment fragment, String fragName, String backStackName, boolean value) {
        fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frag_container, fragment, fragName);

        if (value) {
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(backStackName);
        }

        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }
```

I have made a master class which extends fragments and this master class is extended by other class.Now is my approach right???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is right. I have implemented with same approach like this.

```
public void replaceFragment (Fragment fragment){

    try {
        String backStateName =  fragment.getClass().getName();
        String fragmentTag = backStateName;


        FragmentManager manager =getSupportFragmentManager();
        boolean fragmentPopped = manager.popBackStackImmediate (backStateName, 0);
        if (!fragmentPopped && manager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag) == null){ 
            FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment, fragmentTag);
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            ft.addToBackStack(backStateName);
            ft.commit();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

Hope this will help you...

replace your "startFragment" method with "replaceFragment"
and extend MasterFragment where you want

Comment: Can you tell me what this will do??

Comment: @user3917131 replace your "startFragment" method with "replaceFragment"
and extend MasterFragment where you want

Comment: what if i dont wanna add a fragment to backstack

Comment: ft.addToBackStack(null); use this

Comment: thankyou,so in my every fragment proj i should use this code to add or replace fragments??